# Is there a way to get the index value when using .... Array.IndexOf?

Tags: c#

How to know at which index the value exists, when I use `Array.IndexOf`?

I don't like to use Loop because it lags.

```
if (Array.IndexOf(myarray, myvalue) > -1)
{
     Console.WriteLine("The value exists in myarray[" + " "+ "]");
};
```

Comment: If the items are compared by value then `IndexOf` would do it, otherwise, a loop may be required.

Comment: And how exactly do you suppose IndexOf works? It also uses a loop, you don't like to **see** loop.

Comment: @tanveerBadar Loop really lags :/

Comment: @FaresChebil You are likely doing something wrong in your loop then.

Comment: Loops are an essential part of programming and a simple loop should not slow down your program. If you have a lot of data in the array, maybe use a better data structure than an array

Comment: Guys , i used loop in my game server  , but it lags the send & receive  , cause i have to check stuffs  before sending it  :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the result of `IndexOf()` and use that.

```
var result = Array.IndexOf(myarray, myvalue);
if ( result > -1 )
    Console.WriteLine("the value existe in myarray[" + result + "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Capturing the value is the best way to go, but if you only need the value once, another way you could do this without a loop is to use the `.Contains()` method as the condition, and then the `IndexOf()` method inside the `if` body (if you're willing to sacrifice a small amount of performance for a small amount of readability):

```
var myArray = new string[] { "zero", "one", "two"};
var searchTerm = "two";

// Note that 'Contains' is an extension method that requires a reference to System.Linq
if (myArray.Contains(searchTerm))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found item '{0}' at index: {1}",
        searchTerm, Array.IndexOf(myArray, searchTerm));
}
```

Output:

[image]